# Layout in Android issue

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I am trying to do a `View` like this :

[Listview http://leyth.dk/upload/server/php/files/NewScreen.png](http://leyth.dk/upload/server/php/files/NewScreen.png)

**Problem**

How I Can put the Zip Label with the same line at `TextView`?

I tried to do a `LinearLayout` for both but I couldn't get it to work, I hope someone can help me with it.

** Update --> Forgotten Code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Navn : "
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip" />
    <!-- Description label -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/adresse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Adresse : "
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#acacac"
        android:text="Post Nr : "
        android:paddingBottom="2dip">
    </TextView>
    <!-- Linear layout for cost and price Cost: Rs.100 -->
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!-- Cost Label -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/by"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="By : "
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    <!-- Price Label -->       
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So, What you have try ?

Comment: It seems like i didnt put the Xml code. here its

Comment: Excuse me, could you tell me the name of the app you used to draw the image? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Lai Vung : sure its called --> WireframeSketcher Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please change the labels and font size. i just coded the first part

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try using a relative layout check the following code

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:text="Name :"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:text="Address :"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="Zip :"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="getname();"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="getaddress();"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="getzip();"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use weightsum:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Name Label -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightsum="10"
         >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:textColor="#43bd00"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Navn : "
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip" />
       <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="7"
    />
       </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightsum="10"
         >
      <!-- add other lable and text  here(as above)-->
     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightsum="10"
         >
      <!-- add other lable and text  here(as above)-->
     </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and so on....Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [GridLayout](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html). Its built for such *labelled form* scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Try using FrameLayout for placing zip label above TextView.Hope this helps.